# Vue watcher is triggered with two parameters, but not with one

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

Let's say I have a childComponent and a parentComponent.

From the parentComponent I am passing a prop called 'sections' to the childComponent.

The 'sections' state from the parentComponent is initalized by default with null.

Within the created() hook of the parentComponent I'm calling an API within an async function and the 'sections' state is being changed.

Within the childComponent I setup a watcher to see when the 'sections' prop is being changed.

The issue that I encountered is that the watcher is triggered only when I have two parameters inside the watcher:

```
watch() {
   sections(newVal, oldVal) { console.log('this is triggered'); }
}
```

this is not triggered:

```
watch() {
   sections(val) { console.log('this is not triggered'); }
}
```

I can definitely use the watcher with both parameters, but I was just curious what could cause this.

Comment: There should be no difference, so there's no answer in general, the problem is specific to your case. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Btw it's `sections(newVal, oldValue)`, not `sections(oldValue, newVal)`

Comment: Yep, you're right. Edited the code. I will try to give an example.

Answer (score -1):

hm... it's strange... actually it should work.. here is my code.. in (Vue 3 SFC ts) is watching without oldval

```
watch(() => name.value, (newVal:any) => {
  .....
 }
```